# Args statement in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, args

In Eclipse, when I type:

```
string name = "value";
```

This always becomes

```
string name args=args "value";
```

when I press enter.
What is this `args`? And why does it appear everytime I use `=`?

Comment: You're probably misunderstanding autocompletion.

Comment: Are you inside a function called static void main(String[] args) when you see this?

Comment: I just fixed the problem. I just change the activation triggers in the preferences settings. @SLaks yer right it's indeed in the autocompletion side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try capitalizing String, if you weren't earlier. Args is the command line arguments from the main function.

Comment: String dfd args=args "sample";
I just did that, it happens again